# Получение ответа из json

Tags: python, json

```
er = {"errors":[{"code":"loginInvalidFormat","message":"Для входа надо указать либо логин, либо мобильный телефон, либо e-mail. Введённое значение не соответствует ничему из перечисленного.","detail":"Для входа надо указать либо логин, либо мобильный телефон, либо e-mail. Введённое значение не соответствует ничему из перечисленного."}]}
json_str = json.dumps(er)
json_str = json.loads(json_str)
print(json_str["errors"]["code"])
# ошибка 
    print(json_str["errors"][{"code"}])
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not set
```

Answer (score 0):

ну так у вас по ключу "errors" список, поэтому и не работает получение по ключу "code" ибо это список, а не словарь

вот так работало бы:

```
print(json_str["errors"][0]["code"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(json_str["errors"][0]["code"])
```

решил проблему сорь, надо сначало смотреть вопросы других пользователей потом уже писать но в итоге разобрался сам